# Consul service catalog to store important urls

Tags: consul

I have a web application which send rest api calls to external services. As of now I have all the urls hardcoded in my application and I intend to store these urls in consul service catalog. Here are few questions related to this.

1) How do I store this url in service catalog?https://prepiam.toronto.ca.ibm.com/idaas/oidc/endpoint/default/authorize?client_id=ssdfsjdfsdfew&response_type=code&scope=openid&redirect_url=https://localhost:9000/mydashboard"
Will I be able to access this as a key value pair in my application. Is there any link to help understand the use and purpose of service catalog?

I also need to store some urls like https://localhost:9000/users. I was hoping I could store this url in parts like hostname,port,base_url etc.

Answer (score 1):

Consul has a ["key-value"](https://www.consul.io/docs/agent/http/kv.html) storage, i.e. you can store any data using some key and get it back. You can store pretty much everything there (with sane limit for size of data,though) but you need to construct all storage functions by yourself.

In a case of URL you can just URL as value, or split it into parts - just take note that all operation should be simple 'get-by-key' and 'put-by-key'.

Comment: Storing urls would be good practice to be stored in consul key-value store or service catalog?